# Extract CAB files with PHP

Tags: php, cab

Running PHP on IIS6, how can I open and extract the contents of a CAB-file? Is there any way of doing this witout using exec? I don't have permission to run stuff with exec.

Answer (score 1):

Without external tools like [cabextract](http://www.cabextract.org.uk/) this won't work. PHP has no functions for this.

Comment: ...unless someone has understood the CAB file structure and written everything necissary in plain PHP?

Comment: that's of course right. maybe there's a PEAR-lib or something, but I don't think so anyways...

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately too long as a comment. I wrote a PHP based *cab-archive reader* a long time ago. Seeing how there is still interest, I put the sources online with the caveat that the project is not pretty, rather limited (no extraction of compressed/stored files) and was not written by a proficient programmer. It may only serve as a starting point.

- Github: [php-cab-reader](https://github.com/lsauer/php-cab-reader)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library for extraction of CAB archives: https://github.com/wapmorgan/CabArchive

- Extraction of **uncompressed** files is supported on all versions.
- Extraction of compressed archives with **MSZip compression** works only on latest PHP versions (7.0.22+, 7.1.8+, 7.2.0).
- Extraction of
  compressed archives with **LZX compression** is not supported.