# How to get list of files in an archive?

Tags: php, file, indexing, archive

I want to generate a list of files in an archive. How can I implement this?

For example: I have a self-extracting CAB archive, so I want to get list of files in it, something like this:

```
 File size | Date       Time     | Name
-----------+---------------------+-------------
      6101 | 21.09.2007 17:38:00 | Advanced.tv_
      5661 | 21.09.2007 17:38:00 | CAD.tv_
   4949932 | 21.09.2007 17:38:00 | data1.cab
     29080 | 21.09.2007 17:38:00 | data1.hdr
```

ADDED: This thing should be OS-independent. It may use a cross-platform *opensource* application, like 7-ZIP.

Comment: This question will have a different answer for different types of archive. Are you asking about .CAB specifically?

Comment: Googling `php extract cab` leads me to this: [Extract CAB files with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560216/extract-cab-files-with-php)

Comment: Austin, Pekka, it should support as many archive types as possible. And yes, including CAB and ZIP.

Comment: Dagon, Windows. But we are moving to Debian next month. So it will be much better, if a solution will be OS-independent.

Comment: StackOverflow is no substitute for Google.  If you have a question on how to use a particular "cross-platform *opensource application" that claims to do what you want, that's another thing altogether.

Comment: Excuse me this is a duplicate of what ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know PHP is not able to read a CAB archive.

For zip, gz, tgz, bz2, tbz archives you can try using the following:

- http://pear.php.net/package/File_Archive
- http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Zip

Edit: Try [Lo-Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901946/lo-sauer)'s [PHP CAB Reader](https://github.com/lsauer/php-cab-reader)

Comment: I wrote a cab reader in PHP, although it is very limited and only works for stored, uncompressed files in cab archives: https://github.com/lsauer/php-cab-reader